# How to replace '&' character at the last comma in a string?

Tags: sql, sql-server

My input string in

```
Declare @ListOfContactType nvarchar(1000) 
SET @ListOfContactType = 'Customer,Supplier,Financier,Employee'
```

Please help me to get output as `'Customer,Supplier,Financier & Employee'`

Note: string in @ListOfContactType may vary.

Comment: You can accept any one answer below. If it helps to you.

Answer (score 2):

Solution:

```
Declare @ListOfContactType nvarchar(1000);
Declare @Position int;

Set @ListOfContactType = 'Customer,Supplier,Financier,Employee';
Set @Position = CHARINDEX(',', REVERSE(@ListOfContactType));

select REVERSE(STUFF(REVERSE(@ListOfContactType), @position, 1, '&'))
```

Expected Output:

```
Customer,Supplier,Financier&Employee
```

Reverse the string to get the index, than reverse again after replacing for expected output.

Answer (score 1):

Find the last occurence of , with the help of charindex and replaced that with & by using `stuff` function.

```
DECLARE @LISTOFCONTACTTYPE NVARCHAR(1000)

SET @LISTOFCONTACTTYPE = 'CUSTOMER,SUPPLIER,FINANCIER,EMPLOYEE'

SELECT STUFF(@LISTOFCONTACTTYPE, 
             LEN(@LISTOFCONTACTTYPE) - CHARINDEX(',', REVERSE(@LISTOFCONTACTTYPE))+1, 1, ' & ') AS OUT_PUT
```

Comment: ,It's given following result with comma. Customer,Supplier,Financie & ,Employee

Comment: @Mansoor Updated post.

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare @ListOfContactType nvarchar(1000) 
Declare @LastOccuredAt int
SET @ListOfContactType = 'Customer,Supplier,Financier,Employee'
SET @LastOccuredAt=LEN(@ListOfContactType) - CHARINDEX(',',REVERSE(@ListOfContactType)) 
print substring(@ListOfContactType,1,@LastOccuredAt) + ' & ' + substring(@ListOfContactType,@LastOccuredAt +2,(len(@ListOfContactType)-@LastOccuredAt))
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to find the last occurance of a comma in your string. Since T-SQL doesn't offer a way to search backwards the trick is to reverse the string and search from the beginning.

```
LEN(@ListOfContactType) - CHARINDEX(',', REVERSE(@ListOfContactType))
```

Will give you this position. You can then replace the comma with `STUFF` but keep in mind that you have to correct the position there for one character. So

```
STUFF( @ListOfContactType, 1 + LEN(@ListOfContactType) - CHARINDEX(',', REVERSE(@ListOfContactType)), 1, ' & ')
```

should give your desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Simple and very straightforward query:

```
Declare @ListOfContactType nvarchar(1000) 
SET @ListOfContactType = 'Customer,Supplier,Financier,Employee'

select reverse(stuff(reverse(@ListOfContactType),charindex(',',reverse(@ListOfContactType)),1,' & '))
```